# In Windows-7 run command from batch file with reduced priority

Tags: windows-7, priority, batch-file

I am starting a long, memory and CPU-intensive run. I know how to change the process priority manually from the task manager.

Is there a way that I can run it at low priority from a `.bat` file, since that is how I start it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start it with the Start /low command and parameter, e g Start /low c:\foo.exe.

If you want to start a program with spaces in path and with arguments, you need to specify a title as well:

```
start /low "Title of cmd window" "c:\program files\blah\blah.exe" --argument
```

Comment: Note that this starts it in a new window if the command itself is a .bat. The window doesn't close when the command done. That works fine for me, but could be annoying.

Comment: @Brian: You can start `cmd /c foo.bat` in that case.

Comment: "If you want to start a program with spaces [...] you need to specify a title as well"  ... this made my day !

Comment: Note: any programs started from within the `foo.bat` retain the lower priority, great for multi step scheduled long running tasks like backups.